# how to make Simple Membership create tables with default dbo schema

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have an issue with Simple Membership with SQL server using Entity framework code first.

When I run

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection( "MyDB", "Users", 
                                          "UserID", "Username", true);
```

on my own development pc, It creates the following tables

```
dbo.Users
dbo.webpages_Membership
dbo.webpages_Roles
dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles
```

But, when I run the site on a host it creates the tables as:

```
myusername.Users
myusername.webpages_Membership
myusername.webpages_Roles
myusername.webpages_UsersInRoles
```

Please, 
how do I get the simple membership provider to create the tables with the default dbo schema?

Answer (score 2):

You can find here a good way to do this without specify a default schema for your user.

You just need to follow [this implementation](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) and define the default schema.
Like this:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership", Schema = "SCHEMA_NAME")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection uses the default schema 
assigned to your Database User to create\access the tables 
for the SimpleMembershipProvider.
```

So you need to change the default schema your user has on the Database on your host.

Does your host allow you to set the default schema for your Database User?